# bash date not using the set timezone

Tags: bash, timezone, time, date

I have

```
export TZ="/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London"
```

in my `.bashrc` file, but the following output the time in UTC (GMT)

```
export TM=`date +%H%M%S`
export DTTM="`date +%a\ %F\ %T\ %Z`"
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should just export the time zone, not the full path:

```
export TZ="Europe/London"
```